# Sometimes the implementation does not work when the application is disconnected

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to delete some data in google firesore when the app disconnects.
However, the following code does not work correctly.

Also, it works correctly in the simulator, but not on the actual machine.

```
import Firebase
import FirebaseFirestore

class SceneDelegate: UIResponder, UIWindowSceneDelegate {
    
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    var window: UIWindow?
    
    func sceneDidDisconnect(_ scene: UIScene) {
        db.collection("parentCol").document("doc").collection("col_1").document("doc_1").delete()
        db.collection("parentCol").document("doc").collection("col_2").document("doc_2").delete() 
        db.collection("parentCol").document("doc").delete()
    }
}
```

### What I expect

---

(I am producing a game application.)

- The host determines the roomId and produces a room.
- Guests connect to the room via that roomId.
- When the game ends or the player disconnects from the application, server data that is no longer needed is deleted.

```
//data structure

col: rooms
   |
   |- doc: 1234 (roomId)
   |     |
   |     |- col: members
   |           |
   |           |- doc: name ( here I store an array of String)
   |                 |- 1: Tom
   |                 |- 2: Ares
   |                 |- 3: Michael
   |
   |- doc: abc (roomId)
```

### What I tried

---

It worked fine in the simulator.
However, when I tried it on the actual device, it did not work correctly.

Only `doc_1` was deleted in the following code.↓

```
    func sceneDidDisconnect(_ scene: UIScene) {
       db.collection("parentCol").document("doc").collection("col_1").document("doc_1").delete()
       db.collection("parentCol").document("doc").delete()
    }
```

---

Only `doc` was deleted in the following code.↓

```
    func sceneDidDisconnect(_ scene: UIScene) {
       db.collection("parentCol").document("doc").delete()
    }
```

---

Nothing is deleted when the following code.↓

```
   func sceneDidDisconnect(_ scene: UIScene) {
        db.collection("parentCol").document("doc").collection("col_1").document("doc_1").delete()
        db.collection("parentCol").document("doc").collection("col_2").document("doc_2").delete() 
        db.collection("parentCol").document("doc").delete()
    }
```

---

I know that after an app is disconnected, it will only run for a few seconds. But that should be more than enough time to delete data.

If you have any solutions, please let me know.

My native language is not English, so sorry if it is hard to read.

Comment: For clarity, when your app is disconnected... it's *disconnected* and can no longer send commands to Firebase. The only option is to delete cached data and then when the app re-connects, it will sync. That requires persistence to be on. The only thing that *can* happen upon disconnect is if you install an `onDisconnect` handler on the server to perform some function when the client disconnects. Can you clarify the expectation so we can properly advise you?

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
I have edited the question to clarify expectations.
If you have time, please continue to help me.

Comment: Yay! Much more clear. Unfortunately, that's not going to work. Once you're app disconnects there is no flow of data in either direction so you cannot make changes on the server afterwards. Your best bet is to use the onDisconnect feature of the Realtime Database to trigger a function on the server that performs the cleanup. There's actually documentation on [Build presence in Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/presence) that sounds like exactly what you need

Comment: Sorry for the delay in replying. Thanks for the advice. Your advice helps me so much. I will try to rewrite the code again using your advice.

Answer (score 0):

I think what happens on simulator (i.e. `sceneDidDisconnect` is a few seconds delayed) is rather an anomaly, while the behavior you see on device is correct (i.e. `sceneDidDisconnect` is almost instantaneous).

I recommend that you re-read [Managing your app’s life cycle](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/app_and_environment/managing_your_app_s_life_cycle). It states that scene disconnection is for cleanup, while any data operations should be done *prior to that* when the app is about to leave the foreground-active state:

> - Upon leaving the foreground-active state, save data and quiet your app’s behavior. See Preparing your UI to run in the background.
> - Upon entering the background state, finish crucial tasks, free up as much memory as possible, and prepare for your app snapshot. See Preparing your UI to run in the background.
> - At scene disconnection, clean up any shared resources associated with the scene.

So use [`sceneWillResignActive(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscenedelegate/3197919-scenewillresignactive) to perform the deletion instead. Furthermore: as Apple states -

> Don’t rely on specific app transitions to save all of your app's critical data.

So if you can do these deletions on some other app events, do that, and only use app events as a backup. And also make sure your app handles a situation where the data may still exist on next invocation of the app (because if the app is killed in some more brutal ways may never allow any of the shutdown functions to run).

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
I was still a novice. I will look into the IOS system once again. Thanks to you I have learned one more thing.